# CLIPS performance concerns

Tags: c++, clips

I'm constructing an expert system by embedding CLIPS 6.31 into a C++ application dealing with a medium-sized flow of data and requiring an *almost real-time* response (i. e. total analysis time shouldn't surpass 40 milliseconds). By now I fed some 430 facts to the "entry point" of the inference engine (the knowledge base is comprised by 8 rules, most of which are fired on every iteration, which is achieved through `EnvRefresh(...)` ) in a loop which resulted in the response time oscillating between 600 and 700 ms, which is much bigger than necessary. Is there any way of speeding up the inference? How "heavy" can the rule patterns if real-time response is of importance? Is CLIPS at all suitable for a real time application like that or should it be replaced with CLIPS/R2 or something similar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to analyze performance issues with just a general description of the code. Here are two questions on Stack Overflow illustrating rules that can be rewritten to improve performance:

[How to optimize pattern matching between different templated facts in CLIPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58647480/how-to-optimize-pattern-matching-between-different-templated-facts-in-clips/58648669#58648669)

[CLIPS huge memory usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34614964/clips-huge-memory-usage/34617784#34617784)

You can also compile your C++ program with profiling enabled to see where time is being spent. Using the refresh command as part of your normal execution raises a few red flags.

Last I heard, CLIPS/R2 is no longer available, in part due to the performance improvements in CLIPS 6.3.

Comment: Thank you very much! The links gave me some idea of what might be going on, I made a correction and the problem was gone! I have only one question - why is refresh command a red flag? (I am afraid, I don't have any other option - sensor data comes continuously and **I have to** apply the same rules over and over)

Comment: You're trying to get real-time performance, but you're repeatedly calling a function which forces every activation for your rules back on the agenda. Perhaps this is the best way to achieve the results you want, but it seems unlikely that you have to do it this way. For example, you can get the same rules applied over and over by issuing a reset command and then reasserting the sensor data. Rather than reapplying the same rules over and over again, it could be more efficient to remember the prior result of the applied rules and compute the change to those results for new sensor data.

Comment: This is a good suggestion, but unfortunately I can't issue a reset command as long as it will wipe everything out and "_the prior result of the applied rules_" is a set of facts themselves. How do I save facts outside of the "fact base" (let us put it this way)? I could have saved them as strings, but as far as I have learnt, facts are not designed in a way to be accessed like that. Anyways, in the latter case, I will have to save them, reset the environment and assert them again. Is it really faster than refreshing?

Comment: My prior comment was making two points. First, that there is more than one way to handle continuous sensor data (which may or may not be faster than what you're doing now). Second, that there may be an approach that does not require refreshing the rules which consequently has better performance. I don't know enough about your current approach to suggest a specific way to improve the performance. It's hard to optimize code you can't run to observe its behavior.

Comment: In fact, I've already managed to optimize my code. The root of the problem was the generation of loads of matches. At previous stage of the system development I had to preserve up to 50 prior states. When the system became more complex total analysis time increased, but as long as the preservation was no longer needed I removed a part of code. Your answer just left me wondering if refreshing was mostly an inappropriate approach, but now I see, that it depends. Thus, thank you!